# How to disable an entry field but still be able to see the value in it. Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to disable an entry field but still see the value in it? In Tkinter

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `state` to be `DISABLED`. When the `state` is `DISABLED`, you can't type anything in the text box.

So, for example:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()


e = Entry(window)
e.pack()
def submit():
    e.config(state = DISABLED)

btn = Button(window, text = "submit", command = submit)
btn.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to disable an entry field but still see the value in it

Same as @10 Rep's script. You can do `state` instead of `.config`.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

e = Entry(window)
e.pack()
def submit():
    e['state'] = DISABLED

btn = Button(window, text = "submit", command = submit)
btn.pack()
window.mainloop()
```